# Amazon AWS SDK using Swift and Perfect?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, perfect

Is it possible to leverage the [Amazon Web Services SDK for iOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) in a server-side Swift app developed using the [Perfect](http://www.perfect.org) framework?  I'd like to be able to deploy my Perfect app to AWS and make calls to DynamoDB, S3, etc. from the app.  However, I haven't found any examples showing if that is even possible.  Can the AWS SDK be used server-side, even though it says "for iOS"?  Does it support the Swift Package Manager, which Perfect seems to use for integrating with 3rd party libraries?  If not, does Perfect support CocoaPods for dependency management?

If what I'm attempting feasible, or would I have to write my own integration code using Amazon's RESTful services directly?

Comment: I'm looking to do exactly the same. Did you have success? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

"Original" AWS library does not support Swift Package Manager in that moment, and also uses some Obj-c code (as far as I know), so you can't use it on linux. But there is feature suggestion, so maybe it would be there in future

Now you can use AWS services with that library: https://github.com/noppoMan/aws-sdk-swift though its a bit hacky :)

I use that one in my current projects and it's look like all the basic needs are implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you would probably using Perfect-CURL to perform such tasks; Perfect-MySQL supports RDS, however, you can easily add all SPM compatible 3rd party components as many as need, just edit Package.swift to include; a better idea is to user Perfect Assistant to safely import different components and quickly build / test & deploy to AWS EC2:
http://www.perfect.org/en/assistant/

About Perfect-CURL, there are many examples about Server Side Operations, such as 
https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Cloudinary-ImageUploader-Demo 
which contains how to generate a digital signature in posting files,

also
https://github.com/PerfectServers/SlackBot
with curling API